# Fetching data from Custom Payload Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm using custom payload for notification & I get notification but I'm unable to fetch from Key["data"].
Here is my Payload code

```
{
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "com.xyz.zyxapp",
   "aps" : {
        "alert" : "It's a notification with custom payload!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "content-available" : 0         
    },
    "data" :{
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
    },
  }
```

I'm trying to access data from didreceive method

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
  {
     print(response.notification.request.content.body)
}
```

result is: It's a notification with custom payload!
If anyone can help me with this will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse custom data in notification's `userInfo` property instead of body. `userInfo` is a dictionary of custom information associated with the notification.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let data = userInfo["data"] as? [String: Any] {
        //
        //Do your parsing here..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working directly when i add this code.